# Reduce multiple if else statements

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
My Name:<input class="clr" id="name" type="text" /><span class="clr" id="name_error">Name is required</span> <br /><br />

My Email Adress:<input class="clr" id="email" type="text" /><span class="clr" id="email_error">Email is required</span> <br /><br />

My Organisation Name:<input class="clr" id="organisation" type="text" /><span class="clr" id="org_error">Organisation is required</span> <br /><br />
```

I have 3 input fields. I'm using `span` to display error message when submitting empty fields.

My problem is, if `name` field is empty, we should get `"Name is required"` error, if `email` field is empty, we should get `"email is required"` error and so on.

For this, I'm writing below code.

```
if (name == "")
    $("#name_error").show();
else
    $("#name_error").hide();

if (email == "")
    $("#email_error").show();
else
    $("#email_error").hide();

if (organisation == "")
    $("#org_error").show();
else
    $("#org_error").hide();
```

Is there any way to reduce if/else statements?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Using jQuery effectively, you can do this way.

```
$('input.clr').each(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "")
        $(this).next('span.clr').show();
});
```

Before that, we need to hide them this way:

```
$('span.clr').hide();
```

Comment: I would assume a `hide` is needed as well?

Comment: You're right, that's simpler and more reasonable in this specific case (supposing the DOM doesn't change and the error span always follows the input).

Comment: +1, given the provided HTML, this is a nice solution. If HTML structure is possibly changing then switching to class or even data attributes for association between field and message would be another way to go and the same `.each` could be used.

Comment: Even if the HTML gets changed, it is kind of scalable.

Comment: @RanadheerReddy Have you included jQuery? Lemme create a fiddle and let you know...

Comment: sory. i have one more span element in between <input> and error <span>. i have to show() the second span after input @praveen kumar

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25529/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-ranadheer-reddy)

Answer (score 3):

You could do this :

```
   var obj = window; // or something else, depending on your scope
   ['name', 'email', 'organisation'].forEach(function(v) {
       var $e = $('#'+v+'_error');
       if (obj[v]=="") $e.show();
       else $e.hide();
   });
```

Note that

- this supposes a little more strictness, with the replacement of "org" by "organisation"
- I tried to mimic your code but changing at the root (i.e. where you fill the variables like `name`) would allow for a simpler code
- if you know the DOM doesn't change and the error span always follows the input, Praveen's answer is probably simpler and suited

Comment: Note that use of `forEach` will break compatibility in IE8 and older unless you use a shim.

Comment: +1 for being open to either interpretation of organization (organisation). :)